# Importing SCSS in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I have installed [fourseven:scss](https://github.com/fourseven/meteor-scss) but the problem I am facing is that the following line results in the `Unexpected token` error.

```
@import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.scss';
```

I think this is because the application doesn't recognize `@import` directive.

Do I need to install something else to make this directive work?

Comment: why not just use ```import```? Any specific reason to use ```@import```?

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you using slick-carousel from npm?

If not, use `npm install --save slick-carousel` in the Meteor directory. Then in your CSS use this syntax (replacing `foundation-sites` with your own).

`@import '{}/node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/foundation.scss';`

Comment: Could you post the contents of your `.meteor/packages` file and the `.css` file with its path in a pastebin?